# CSS animations are not working when added by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I am trying to make a burger Icon button.
When you click it, the top and bottom lines are supposed to move to the left, and the middle one is supposed to disappear, but when I click it nothing happens. I've already turned on the JavaScript in the browser and that didn't work. I thought it was the code editor so I downloaded atom (I usually use VS code) but that didn't work also.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(!menuOpen){
        menuBtn.classList.add('open');
        menuOpen = true;
    } else {
        menuBtn.classList.remove('open');
        menuOpen = false;
    }
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    background: #272727;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    border: 3px solid #fff
}

.menu-btn__burger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,201,47,.2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(16px);
}

/* ANIMATION */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
    transform: translateX( -50px);
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You can just use `menuBtn.classList.toggle("open")` instead of if else conditions.

Comment: Your code works well for me. Does the console show errors when click?

Comment: I just edited your question and added a snippet and the code worked fine

Comment: I agree with @s.kuznetsov. Pasted to CodePen and it does what you described.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov so then it must be something wrong with my computer ? because this isn't the first time i've had a problem like this. My document.querySelector() also doesn't work

Comment: figured it out, There was something wrong with chrome.. it works in firefox

Answer (score 0):

It worked just fine as it was... but you could shorten it with one-liner:

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("open", menuOpen = !menuOpen)
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    background: #272727;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    border: 3px solid #fff
}

.menu-btn__burger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn.open
{
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS hamburger Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is Already Fine. It works well. Maybe you forget to refresh the window :)
Also, if you didn't knew already, you could use `elem.classList.toggle("class")` instead of `if-else` condition.

```js
const menuBtn = document.querySelector('.menu-btn');
let menuOpen = false;
menuBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menuBtn.classList.toggle("open");
    menuOpen = !menuOpen;
});
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
    background: #272727;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.menu-btn {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
    border: 3px solid #fff
}

.menu-btn__burger {
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgb(255, 101, 47, .2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before,
.menu-btn__burger::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    height: 6px;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(255,201,47,.2);
    transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
}

.menu-btn__burger::before {
    transform: translateY(-16px);
}

.menu-btn__burger::after {
    transform: translateY(16px);
}

/* ANIMATION */
.menu-btn.open .menu-btn__burger {
    transform: translateX( -50px);
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CSS hamburger Animation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu-btn">
        <div class="menu-btn__burger"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```